# How to insert an HTML table in Google Calendar's description

Tags: google-calendar

How can I insert a rich text table into a Google calendar event so that the invitees do not have to worry about tabs or fonts?

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar description text is sent to email clients with little to no modification. [Convert the rich text table to HTML tags](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) if you can safely assume the invitees have rich text email clients.